# Easy to to serialize/toString a set of tuples in python

Tags: python

Say I have a set like

```
s=([1,2],[2,3])
```

I wanted do something like "\n".join(s) but then get an `TypeException` about

```
expecting a string and getting a tuple
```

Comment: the error is very clear `join` function expecting a string and getting a tuple

Comment: I know that.  I was hoping maybe there was some list compresion syntax surgar versus iterating through all the elements in a for loop

Comment: so did you have try any thing to solve your problem ? all you need is a search about convert `set` to string or pass set to `join`

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: Your error message is invalid. It should be: expecting a string and getting a LIST. You can convert anything to string using str function str([1,2,3]) will give '[1, 2, 3]'.

Answer (score 5):

What do you want to serialize the objects for? If they are to be used by Python, you could use pickle -

```
import pickle
s = pickle.dumps(([1,2],[2,3]))
```

If not by Python,, then distinguishing between tuples and lists is not important, and you can just use json:

```
import json
s = json.dumps(...)
```

If you want it as a string, that can be interpreted as a Python expression, by a humna, Python's eval, or better `ast.literal_eval`, you can simply use the repr of your expression:

```
s = repr(([1,2],[2,3]))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"\n".join(map(str,s))
```

would cast each item as a string first

or

```
"\n".join([str(x) for x in s])
```

if you prefer list comprehensions